# How to challenge my custom authentication middleware?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, openid-connect, owin, multi-tenant

Microsoft provides a whole lot of libraries to allow for various authentication methods including OpenID connect using the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect package. However, this package is not really designed for multi-tenant scenarios if the tenants require different options.

To solve this issue, I got creative and thought of creating a "middleware router" as an alternative. That is, I created my own middleware and use that middleware to invoke the actual `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` instance manually with tenant-specific options like so:

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    if (context.Authentication.User == null)
    {
        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
        options.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;

        // configure options dynamically...

        var openIdConnectMiddleware = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware(Next, app, options);
        return openIdConnectMiddleware.Invoke(context);
    }

    return Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

However, I fail to explicitly "challange" this new authentication middleware:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void OpenIdConnectLogin()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

So far I was unable to figure out how I can associate the `AuthenticationType` with my custom middleware. How can I "challenge" my own authentication middleware?